# mysql stalled after i kill process and the disk is 100% full

Tags: mysql

My server is 94% full, so i try to change some mysql column from int to tinyint to free some space, however, one table is so large that when i run

```
ALTER TABLE `app_play_data` CHANGE `countryId` `countryId` TINYINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

it began to copy data to tmp table.
when i run show processlist, the state is copy to tmp table.

then i use kill to stop the process

it shows killed after i do that, however, the state changes to repair by sorting.

but the disk is 100% full now, and the state just stayed the same for long time,

How can I fix this without damaging the table?

Answer (score 1):

Killing a process that are doing a "alter table" is very dangerous!

MySQL don't like it when the disk is 100% full.

Best solution is to free up some space or grow the drive NOW!.

In most cases MySQL will wait until there are free space and continue doing its work.

Comment: the problem is we dont have more space right now, so is there way to repair it without adding space

Comment: dont you have a log table or transaction log, or something that can give a little space?

Comment: so if i stop mysql server , there is a solution ? the thing is i dont know if i can restart the server since it is 100% full and i dont know where the tmp table is .

Comment: are you running myisam or innodb?

Comment: for myisam you can look into mysql data dir, here you should be able to see the table data files, and as far as i remember there should be a "app_play_data.tmp" containing the temp table data

Comment: i checked the folder, no app_play_data.tmp